# Stored procedure performance improve postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL. I have some stored procedures which runs on daily basis and aggregates some values from tables.As they are running daily, how can we improve performance of queries by skipping the previous day's execution on today.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer? Provide more information about your sps and the expected behavior. Your question is far too vague for anyone to feel compelled to answer it.

Comment: I am doing some aggregations of values and storing in an another table.on the next day again I am calculating the same values with new data+previous data and update the same table with new values.So daily I am querying on the same table for aggregations. how can we improve the performance on this case?

Comment: "*how can we improve performance of queries by skipping the previous day's execution on today*" - You're saying you want to improve performance by only calculating *today's* data?

Comment: Yes ..I want to calculate today's data..

Comment: It's difficult to give you suggestions without seeing the aggregation code or the table schema. But it'll be something like this... presumably there's a field in your table which has a date or timestamp field, so your agg code is something like `blah_agg(value) FROM table_name WHERE ...`, add a condition like `your_date_field = CURRENT_DATE` if it's a date field, or `your_timestamp_field BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day'` if it's a timestamp field.